# RemoteActorRefProvider ClassNotFound

Tags: java, scala, akka

I'm struggling trying to get remote actors setup in Scala. I'm running Scala 2.10.2 and Akka 2.2.1.

I compile using [I've shortened the paths on the classpath arg for clarity sake]:

```
$ scalac -classpath "akka-2.2.1/lib:akka-2.2.1/lib/scala-library.jar:akka-2.2.1/lib/akka:akka-2.2.1/lib/akka/scala-reflect-2.10.1.jar:akka-2.2.1/lib/akka/config-1.0.2.jar:akka-2.2.1/lib/akka/akka-remote_2.10-2.2.1.jar:akka-2.2.1/lib/akka/akka-kernel_2.10-2.2.1.jar:akka-2.2.1/lib/akka/akka-actor_2.10-2.2.1.jar:." [file.scala]
```

I've continuously added new libraries trying to debug this - I'm pretty sure all I really need to include is akka-remote, but the others shouldn't hurt.

No issues compiling.

I attempt to run like this:

```
$ scala -classpath "[same as above]" [application]
```

And I receive a NSM exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.<init>(java.lang.String, akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings, akka.event.EventStream, akka.actor.Scheduler, akka.actor.DynamicAccess)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2810)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053)
...
```

Looking into the source code, it appears that Akka 2.2.X's flavor of this constructor takes 4 arguments (the Scheduler is removed). But in Akka < 2.2.X, the constructor takes 5 args.

Thus, I'm thinking my classpath isn't setup quite right. At compile-time, Scala must be finding the <2.2.X flavor. I don't even know where it would be finding it, since I only have Akka 2.2.1 installed.

Any suggestions!? Thanks! (Please don't say to use SBT).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the Scala distribution contains akka-actor 2.1.0 and helpfully puts that in the boot class path for you. We very strongly recommend using a dependency manager like sbt or maven when building anything which goes beyond the most trivial projects.

Comment: That's frustrating. Why would the "scala" script not place the user-defined libraries from the "-classpath" argument ahead of the [scala]/lib/* libraries on the bootpath?

Comment: I understand your frustration; the boot classpath comes first, which is one of the reasons why the scala script uses it (the main part of that reason is that switching off byte-code verification makes scalac start quite a bit faster).

Comment: What does "which is one of the reasons why scala script uses it" mean? Also: what does mvn/sbt do to avoid the boot classpath version?

Comment: I am ending up back at this problem repeatedly (2 1/2 months after my prior post). This is a significant problem.

Comment: So what is the way to get the required version of akka installed ahead of the scala 2.10 supplied ones?

Comment: It's simple: do not use the scripts from the Scala distribution to run your projects, that is not what they are made for. If you use a dependency manager like maven, gradle, sbt, etc. then you get the right class path plus tools for packaging and deployment. Otherwise it boils down to starting the JVM, which you can (and should) do easily yourself.

Comment: A _very_ ugly workaround that proves this point and that allowed me to at least get some prototype code running in "local" mode on an IntelliJ Scala plugin project with Spark 1.0.2 and scala 2.10.2 was to temporarily remove the akka-actors.jar file from the scala-2.10.2/lib/ (I presume it now uses the correct akka 2.2.3 libs with shaded protobuf that are included in spark-project)

Comment: I am back here .. again .. after recompiling everything (unnecessarily) having been concerned about potential scala versions mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in another answer, the problem is that `scala` puts a different version of Akka into the bootclasspath.

To more directly answer your question (as you said you don't want to use sbt): you can execute your program with `java` instead of `scala`. You just have to put the appropriate Scala jars into the classpath.

Here is a [spark-dev message about the problem](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-dev/201312.mbox/%3CCAPh_B=ass2NcrN41t7KTSoF1SFGce=N57YMVyukX4hPcO5YN2Q@mail.gmail.com%3E). The important part is: "the workaround is to use java to launch the application instead of scala. All you need to do is to include the right Scala jars (scala-library and scala-compiler) in the classpath."