# Mixing up of Scala library supplied akka-actors.jar and application specific version

Tags: scala, akka

The following SOF explains why akka related method not found exceptions may occur: TL;DR scala boot loader puts scala libraries version of akka-actors first in classpath

[RemoteActorRefProvider ClassNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009133/remoteactorrefprovider-classnotfound)

However simply removing the scala library version in favor of the custom one causes other issues:

```
14/10/28 09:30:23 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(steve); users with modify permissions: Set(steve)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.typesafe.config.Config.getDuration(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)J
    at akka.util.Helpers$ConfigOps$.akka$util$Helpers$ConfigOps$$getDuration$extension(Helpers.scala:125)
```

So it is not clear what is the correct way to handle custom akka-actor jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround for this is a bit surprising.  The *scala* interpreter is *not* the way to go. Instead fall back to the (drum roll..) **java** interpreter to run the (yes scala!) program.

The reason is that the scala interpreter adds in various things - including the akka classes into the boot classpath. Apparently no usable way around that.

To run with java we will need to include the $SCALA_home/lib/*  in the classpath. After that - it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this JIRA. I think spark-core 1.3.1 package is including incorrect typesafe config APIs.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9441
Try following maven or equivalent gradle ,sbt dependencies

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
   <artifactId>config</artifactId>
   <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
  </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
 <artifactId>config</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It appears this were  not an answer - it should be a comment.

Comment: I reported workaround in that JIRA ticket. I just pasted back here for you

Comment: Sure - it is interesting info : but it is not an answer.. but do what you will.